# Cannot align detailTextLabel of TableViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I have a table view controller and in cellForRowAtindex Path method im using both textlabel and detail textlabel. Im trying to left align the detail textlabel like as follows.

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

But it doesnt reflect in my table view. Any Idea?
Now i could go for a custom cell. But what i thought was that it's a waste of time, coz i just need to fix the alignment.
Itll be greatly appreciated if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: What style `UITableViewCell` are you using?

Comment: Im using UITableViewCellStyleValue1 as the style and.... yes the thing is im using both textlabel and detailTextLabel. textlabel comes left aligned properly, but the detailtextlabel is right aligned. any idea?

Comment: ok.. i used UITableViewCellStyleValue2 and now it is aligned the way i want. But now there is another problem where the textlabel's witdth is not getting set according to the content.. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Desdenova Default `textAlignment` of `detailTextLabel` for `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style is `UITextAlignmentRight`. And it seems it is not possible to change it.